# How to get valid data from query

Tags: sql-server

[image]

This is my result. I want to pick only the first 'in' status and the first 'last' status per date but I am not able to do it.

Comment: didn't understand? explain

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: I want to get Only check 'Status' only one check in and Only One Check Out within each day How to  exclude next record which Status is IN

Comment: Edit your question, don't start to post additional information into the comments. Add a proper title and description of your problem and what you want to archive.

Comment: Do you mean that for `attendDate = '2017-01-10'` you want to fetch only records #10 (first record with `status = 'in'` and #12 (first record with `status = 'out'`)?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question, rephrasing the last sentence. I hope I have understood your problem correctly; if not, please try to explain better what you need. A **small but complete example** would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a window function can help you:

```
select * from 
(select 
 rownum = row_number() 
     over (partition by staffid, 
       convert(varchar(10), attendDate, 126), 
       status 
       order by attendDate)
 , * 
 from test
 ) x 
 where rownum = 1
 order by staffid, attendDate
```

It can also be sensible to select the **last** checkout per day:

```
select * from 
(select 
 rownum = row_number() 
     over (partition by staffid, 
       convert(varchar(10), attendDate, 126), 
       status 
       order by 
         case when status = 'in' then attendDate else 0 end,
         case when status = 'out' then attendDate else 0 end desc
       )
 , * 
 from test
 ) x 
 where rownum = 1
 order by staffid, attendDate
```